# Error in creating BIN File using Binary File C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a Binary File in C# here using the following code below.  It is relatively simple code below.  The RawData variable is a type string[].

```
     using (BinaryWriter bin = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("file.bin", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            foreach (string data in RawData)
            {
                int Byte = Convert.ToInt32(data, 16);
                bin.Write(Byte);


            }

        }
```

Unfortunately the BIN File is produced like this.  It places the correct byte value but then skips the next three bytes and places zeros there and then places the next byte value.  Does anyone know why this happens.  I have used debugged and the bin.Write(Byte), and these extra zeros are NOT sent to this method.

[image: BIN File Capture]

Comment: Use `Convert.ToByte`, and a `byte` type. `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: I am having trouble now when adding this code to my Forms Application.  When I tested this in my simple Console app it worked beautifully.  Now I moved this code into an Event Handler in my Forms application, and it is producing a terrible result of a binary file not even close to the one I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`BinaryWriter.Write(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24e33k1w(v=vs.110).aspx). So yes, it's writing 4 bytes, as documented.

If you only want to write one byte, you should use [`BinaryWriter.Write(byte)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tky7ax3(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

So you probably just want:

```
bin.Write(Convert.ToByte(data, 16));
```

Alternatively, do the whole job in two lines:

```
byte[] bytes = RawData.Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes("file.bin", bytes);
```

Comment: I am having trouble now when adding this code to my Forms Application.  When I tested this in my simple Console app it worked beautifully.  Now I moved this code into an Event Handler in my Forms application, and it is producing a terrible result of a binary file not even close to the one I need.

Comment: Well without any more information about the input, expected output or actual output, it's hard to know what's wrong. I suggest you ask a new question with all the relevant details.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var Byte = Convert.ToByte(....)
```

instead.

You're converting to int, each of which is 4 bytes. So, you see three of them are all zero, and just one byte of the int is the value you expect.